# Access raw sample data from AudioIn object in Processing Sound lib?

Tags: processing, jsyn

How to access the raw sample data from, for example, a processing.sound.AudioIn object ? The array data is there in JSyn (the underlying library), but apparently not exposed in the processing sound lib?

Comment: At the moment, unless you modify the library yourself and recompile it to expose the raw sample data, it is indeed impossible to access it until the library changes. Whenever I needed to do that I've used other Processing sound libraries such as [Minim](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/) or [Beads](http://beadsproject.net/downloads/)

Comment: Thanks George, is this there an example somewhere using Beads?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to the JSyn units then you insert your own custom unit generator into the JSyn flow graph.

You can start from scratch and subclass a UnitGenerator.
Or if you want to process a stream you can subclass a UnitFilter, which has an input and output port.

More information on how to define a custom unit is here:
http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/docs/usersguide.php#Custom

Comment: As best I can tell, you can't get access to the JSyn units because they are in private classes (e.g., [JSynCircuit](https://github.com/processing/processing-sound/blob/master/src/processing/sound/JSynCircuit.java)). So what would be the simplest way to process raw samples from a mono input stream (like a microphone). I'd need a ChannelIn, a subclass of UnitFilter, and a LineOut, or ... ? Some skeleton code would be great...

Comment: You may not be able to access the Processing JSyn units. But perhaps you can just make your own. Try creating your own JSyn synth and then open it with 1 or 2 input channels. Then you can connect filters or other units to that input.
http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/docs/usersguide.php#AudioIput

Here is a simple in/out example.
https://github.com/philburk/jsyn/blob/master/tests/com/jsyn/examples/AudioPassThrough.java